# Python logging: dictConfig and Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a module that logs other modules into a single file, configured with the following dictConfig:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(name)s::%(module)s|%(lineno)s:: %(message)s',
            'class': 'pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'path/to_logs/debug.json',
            'mode': 'a',
            'maxBytes': 1048576,
            'backupCount': 10
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'NOTSET',
            'handlers': ['file'],
        },
    }
}
```

It works fine for scripts. But there is a problem: when importing this logging module into a Flask application or a module imported by this application, the Flask crashes with an error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 558, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 731, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/passenger40/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 320, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/passenger40/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 61, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "passenger_wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
    from HelloFlask import app as application # \u043a\u043e\u0433\u0434\u0430 Flask \u0441\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0443\u0435\u0442, \u043e\u043d \u0438\u0449\u0435\u0442 application. \u0415\u0441\u043b\u0438 \u043d\u0435 \u0443\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u0442\u044c 'as application', \u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442 \u043d\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430\u0435\u0442
  File "/HelloFlask/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from YM.yandex_market import YMConnector
  File "/YM/yandex_market.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pylog.pylog import log, log_decor 
  File "/pylog/pylog.py", line 38, in <module>
    dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 795, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 566, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'
```

I tried to remove `mode` param, but because of this, logging does not work.
In the Flash application, `debug_mode = False`. Also, there are no other loggers in the application
Is it possible to use the config above to log the Flask application and the modules it imports? Or do I need to write a separate module?

Comment: Shouldn't `mode` be `filemode` per [Logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#)

Comment: `mode` also works. I tried to change it to `filemode` and got the same result

Comment: Well looking at code in `handlers.py` for Python  3.6 I don't see `mode` as argument for `TimedRotatingFileHandler`. I do see it for the other file handlers. Have you tried another file handler?

Comment: Oh, tried using `RotatingFileHandler` and removing the `mode` argument, and now the error is gone. But the logging module does not write to the file from Flask and its imports, the rest of the scripts work with logs

Comment: What are the other scripts? How are you using it in Flask? Add answers as update to your question.